compile cordova project in android studio
I am working in ionic to generate an app for android and ios, from the project I send the following command “ionic cordova build android”, to generate everything in the app, here I get an error but I generate the components and the necessary folder to call it in android studio, and at the time of reloading gradle project in android, I get the following error:

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.


Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.application'.
Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions$UnitTestOptions.
> 'void org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectSet.(java.lang.Class)'

I am working with java 8 and I have installed in my computer gradle 8.10.2, I attach screenshots of the error.
error

You're missing alot of information here.... - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
